# Number of functions related to their compositions

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $S$ be a set of $n$ distinct elements. For $k \ge 1$ and a function $f:S \rightarrow S$, define $f^{(k)}(x):=(\underbrace{f\circ f \circ \cdots \circ f}_{\text{$k$ $f$'s}})(x)$ (composite function of $k$ $f$'s).

(1) What is the number of functions $f: S \rightarrow S$ such that $f^{(k)}(x) = x$ for $k \ge 1$?

(2) What is the number of functions $f: S \rightarrow S$ such that $f^{(k)}(x) = f(x)$ for $k \ge 1$?

(3) What is the number of functions $f: S \rightarrow S$ such that $f^{(k)}(x) = f^{(l)}(x)$
for $k,\,l \ge 1$?

Comment: For the first one notice that $f$ must be invertible since $f^{(k-1)}\circ f(x)=(x)$.  Therefore you can view $f$ as a permutation.  This means that the length of the cycles of $f$ must divide $k$ since $f^{(k)}(x)=x$ is the identity.  Not sure if this helps.

Comment: For the second one, define $x \sim_{1} y \iff f(x) = f(y)$ for all $x,y \in S$, and then observe (using previous point) that $f^{(k-1)}$ behaves like a permutation on classes of equivalence of $\sim_1$.

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?